# What constitutes a packet a Wireshark USB bus capture of an isochronous endpoint?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I am working with a USB device which uses UAC to transfer audio data to the USB host and it does this through an isochronous endpoint. I understand that these endpoints are polled on regular intervals but I am having difficulty understanding what my Wireshark captures are actually capturing. Looking at the USB descriptor, it states that the interface sends audio in 96 byte packets but each capture on Wireshark contains 10 packets of 96 bytes. Why could that be? Does Wireshark capture multiple ISO packets and combine them?

The device also has a bulk video endpoint and it has a single packet capture that is 16kB so I am confused why audio is not showing one packet per 96 bytes of data.

Any help understanding what the packet window is showing in the bottom left of the following photo would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Wireshark capture of multiple ISO packets]